# Youtube Analytics API 403 error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Hello i Would like to know somethink.

i follow the steps on the website https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/sample-application#Enable_Authentication

but when i start my application i always have this message :

"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

i have 2 link. 1 to connect on youtube (0auth) how work and give me the token and a  second link that give me the metric, dimenssion... in json. but i have nothink except the message on the top.
js page :

```
(function() {
// Retrieve your client ID from the Google Developers Console at
// https://console.developers.google.com/.
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '261487559881-d9al0muik318iaa07uiasvqb2gliinpm.apps.googleusercontent.com';

var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
];

var ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

// Keep track of the currently authenticated user's YouTube channel ID.
var channelId;

// For information about the Google Chart Tools API, see:
// https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages': ['corechart']});

// Upon loading, the Google APIs JS client automatically invokes this callback.
// See http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Authentication
window.onJSClientLoad = function() {
    gapi.auth.init(function() {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    });
};

// Attempt the immediate OAuth 2.0 client flow as soon as the page loads.
// If the currently logged-in Google Account has previously authorized
// the client specified as the OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID, then the authorization
// succeeds with no user intervention. Otherwise, it fails and the
// user interface that prompts for authorization needs to display.
function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
        immediate: true
    }, handleAuthResult);
}

// Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
        // Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
        // content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
        $('.pre-auth').hide();
        $('.post-auth').show();

        loadAPIClientInterfaces();
    } else {
        // Authorization was unsuccessful. Show content related to prompting for
        // authorization and hide content that should be visible if authorization
        // succeeds.
        $('.post-auth').hide();
        $('.pre-auth').show();

        // Make the #login-link clickable. Attempt a non-immediate OAuth 2.0
        // client flow. The current function is called when that flow completes.
        $('#login-link').click(function() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
                scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
                immediate: false
            }, handleAuthResult);
        });
    }
}

// Load the client interfaces for the YouTube Analytics and Data APIs, which
// are required to use the Google APIs JS client. More info is available at
// http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted#Loading_the_Client
function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
        gapi.client.load('youtubeAnalytics', 'v1', function() {
            // After both client interfaces load, use the Data API to request
            // information about the authenticated user's channel.
            console.log(getUserChannel());
            getUserChannel();
        });
    });
}

// Call the Data API to retrieve information about the currently
// authenticated user's YouTube channel.
function getUserChannel() {
    // Also see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
        // Setting the "mine" request parameter's value to "true" indicates that
        // you want to retrieve the currently authenticated user's channel.
        mine: true,
        part: 'id,contentDetails'
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if ('error' in response) {
            displayMessage(response.error.message);
        } else {
            // We need the channel's channel ID to make calls to the Analytics API.
            // The channel ID value has the form "UCdLFeWKpkLhkguiMZUp8lWA".
            channelId = response.items[0].id;
            // Retrieve the playlist ID that uniquely identifies the playlist of
            // videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel. This value has
            // the form "UUdLFeWKpkLhkguiMZUp8lWA".
            var uploadsListId = response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
            // Use the playlist ID to retrieve the list of uploaded videos.
            getPlaylistItems(uploadsListId);
        }
    });
}

// Call the Data API to retrieve the items in a particular playlist. In this
// example, we are retrieving a playlist of the currently authenticated user's
// uploaded videos. By default, the list returns the most recent videos first.
function getPlaylistItems(listId) {
    // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistitems/list
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
        playlistId: listId,
        part: 'snippet'
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        if ('error' in response) {
            displayMessage(response.error.message);
        } else {
            if ('items' in response) {
                // The jQuery.map() function iterates through all of the items in
                // the response and creates a new array that only contains the
                // specific property we're looking for: videoId.
                var videoIds = $.map(response.items, function(item) {
                    return item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                });

                // Now that we know the IDs of all the videos in the uploads list,
                // we can retrieve information about each video.
                getVideoMetadata(videoIds);
            } else {
                displayMessage('There are no videos in your channel.');
            }
        }
    });
}

// Given an array of video IDs, this function obtains metadata about each
// video and then uses that metadata to display a list of videos.
function getVideoMetadata(videoIds) {
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
        // The 'id' property's value is a comma-separated string of video IDs.
        id: videoIds.join(','),
        part: 'id,snippet,statistics'
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        if ('error' in response) {
            displayMessage(response.error.message);
        } else {
            // Get the jQuery wrapper for the #video-list element before starting
            // the loop.
            var videoList = $('#video-list');
            $.each(response.items, function() {
                // Exclude videos that do not have any views, since those videos
                // will not have any interesting viewcount Analytics data.
                if (this.statistics.viewCount == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                var title = this.snippet.title;
                var videoId = this.id;

                // Create a new <li> element that contains an <a> element.
                // Set the <a> element's text content to the video's title, and
                // add a click handler that will display Analytics data when invoked.
                var liElement = $('<li>');
                var aElement = $('<a>');
                // Setting the href value to '#' ensures that the browser renders the
                // <a> element as a clickable link.
                aElement.attr('href', '#');
                aElement.text(title);
                aElement.click(function() {
                    displayVideoAnalytics(videoId);
                });

                // Call the jQuery.append() method to add the new <a> element to
                // the <li> element, and the <li> element to the parent
                // list, which is identified by the 'videoList' variable.
                liElement.append(aElement);
                videoList.append(liElement);
            });

            if (videoList.children().length == 0) {
                // Display a message if the channel does not have any viewed videos.
                displayMessage('Your channel does not have any videos that have been viewed.');
            }
        }
    });
}

// This function requests YouTube Analytics data for a video and displays
// the results in a chart.
function displayVideoAnalytics(videoId) {
    if (channelId) {
        // To use a different date range, modify the ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS
        // variable to a different millisecond delta as desired.
        var today = new Date();
        var lastMonth = new Date(today.getTime() - ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        var request = gapi.client.youtubeAnalytics.reports.query({
            // The start-date and end-date parameters must be YYYY-MM-DD strings.
            'start-date': formatDateString(lastMonth),
            'end-date': formatDateString(today),
            // At this time, you need to explicitly specify channel==channelId.
            // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/#ids
            ids: 'channel==' + channelId,
            dimensions: 'day',
            sort: 'day',
            // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports
            // for details about the different filters and metrics you can request
            // if the "dimensions" parameter value is "day".
            metrics: 'views',
            filters: 'video==' + videoId
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            // This function is called regardless of whether the request succeeds.
            // The response contains YouTube Analytics data or an error message.
            if ('error' in response) {
                displayMessage(response.error.message);
            } else {
                displayChart(videoId, response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The currently authenticated user's channel ID is not available.
        displayMessage('The YouTube channel ID for the current user is not available.');
    }
}

// This boilerplate code takes a Date object and returns a YYYY-MM-DD string.
function formatDateString(date) {
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = padToTwoCharacters(date.getMonth() + 1);
    var dd = padToTwoCharacters(date.getDate());

    return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
}

// If number is a single digit, prepend a '0'. Otherwise, return the number
//  as a string.
function padToTwoCharacters(number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        return '0' + number;
    } else {
        return number.toString();
    }
}

// Call the Google Chart Tools API to generate a chart of Analytics data.
function displayChart(videoId, response) {
    if ('rows' in response) {
        hideMessage();

        // The columnHeaders property contains an array of objects representing
        // each column's title -- e.g.: [{name:"day"},{name:"views"}]
        // We need these column titles as a simple array, so we call jQuery.map()
        // to get each element's "name" property and create a new array that only
        // contains those values.
        var columns = $.map(response.columnHeaders, function(item) {
            return item.name;
        });
        // The google.visualization.arrayToDataTable() function wants an array
        // of arrays. The first element is an array of column titles, calculated
        // above as "columns". The remaining elements are arrays that each
        // represent a row of data. Fortunately, response.rows is already in
        // this format, so it can just be concatenated.
        // See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable
        var chartDataArray = [columns].concat(response.rows);
        var chartDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartDataArray);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        chart.draw(chartDataTable, {
            // Additional options can be set if desired as described at:
            // https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visdraw
            title: 'Views per Day of Video ' + videoId
        });
    } else {
        displayMessage('No data available for video ' + videoId);
    }
}

// This helper method displays a message on the page.
function displayMessage(message) {
    $('#message').text(message).show();
}

// This helper method hides a previously displayed message on the page.
function hideMessage() {
    $('#message').hide();
}
```

})();

and html page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample YouTube Analytics API Implementation</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login-container" class="pre-auth">This application requires access to your YouTube account.
    Please <a href="#" id="login-link">authorize</a> to continue.
</div>
<div class="post-auth">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div>Choose a Video:</div>
    <ul id="video-list"></ul>
</div>
<a class="plain" href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=261487559881-d9al0muik318iaa07uiasvqb2gliinpm.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://php.com/2/&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly&response_type=token" target="_blank">
    get token </a>
<br><br>
<a class="result" href="">
    to see resultat
</a>
</body>
<script>
    //(function() {
    function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var token = getUrlVars()['access_token'];
            $('.result').attr('href', 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==mine&start-date=2014-01-01&end-date=2014-02-01&metrics=comments,views,likes&dimensions=month&access_token=' + token);
        });
    //});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: post your code please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in your file `index.js` you forgot to close the function. The file need to be ended with

```
})();
```

Second point, why don't try with the exemple on the doc ? i see you use the js of the doc but you change the index.html. Try with the simple example of the doc, it's much better to help you to solve your problem.
Check if you see the error again, then check in your http://console.developers.google.com, make sure you have the good settings for your project.

You need to activate :

```
YouTube Analytics API
YouTube Data API v3
```

You also need a credential, to have your client ID.

[image]

I try at home, with a my client ID and it works perfectly. Try this code with your client ID and see what append.

http://jsbin.com/gokovoje/3/edit?html,js,output

**EDIT**

Replace the function  `checkAuth()` by this :

```
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
      immediate: false
    }, handleAuthResult);
  }
```

**EDIT 2°**

More than 5 videos use `maxResults`

> The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that
>   should be returned in the result set. (integer, 0-50)

Add `maxResults` to the function  `getPlaylistItems(listId)`

```
  // Calls the Data API to retrieve the items in a particular playlist. In this
  // example, we are retrieving a playlist of the currently authenticated user's
  // uploaded videos. By default, the list returns the most recent videos first.
  function getPlaylistItems(listId) {
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
      playlistId: listId,
      part: 'snippet',
      maxResults: 30
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
      if ('error' in response) {
        displayMessage(response.error.message);
      } else {
        if ('items' in response) {
          // jQuery.map() iterates through all of the items in the response and
          // creates a new array that only contains the specific property we're
          // looking for: videoId.
          var videoIds = $.map(response.items, function(item) {
            return item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
          });

          // Now that we know the IDs of all the videos in the uploads list,
          // we can retrieve info about each video.
          getVideoMetadata(videoIds);
        } else {
          displayMessage('There are no videos in your channel.');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes i did it to and copy paste your code i just change de CLIENT_ID in the js for the Client ID for web application.

but i style have the same message : 
"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

i activate YouTube Analytics API and YouTube Data API v3 and use the good credentials Client ID for web application

Comment: @user3392145 , i see, i made an edit, you need to modify a function

Comment: Thx that Work thx a lot @Martialp !! 

last question : now i have my list video but when i click on one i have : No data available for video FngZnEh.
and after the authentification i dont have the acces_token yet

Comment: @user3392145 Make sur the statistics of the video are public if you want to see a graph.

Comment: Thx again @Martialp and last question did you know why i have just the 5 last videos?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using the youtube data api v3.

**Just follow the steps :**

1. make sure u change the checkAuth() and  replace immediate:false. This will be a good way to debug your code.(thats what happened i my case). Also make sure the required APIS are set to ON in  google developers console.

> ```
> function checkAuth() {
>  gapi.auth.authorize({
>  client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
>  scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
> immediate: false
> }, handleAuthResult);
> }
> ```

Once step 1 is followed u might get an error of unknow_client(thats the core issue actually)

2  So go to google developers console.For your project go to **APIs and Auths>Consent screen>** and provide the email address and product name.

3  Save it. Now try executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure your DOM has been loaded before launching this script tutorial.

If you have a doubt, just put all the `<script>` tags just before the closing `</body>` tag.