# Use Firebase Auth information with Youtube API v3

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

In my web-app I use [[image]firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase) to sign-in users, what I get after a successful login is an object like that:

```
{
    uid: ...        
    ...
    stsTokenManager: {
        accessToken: ...
        apiKey: ...
        expirationTime: ...
        refreshToken: ...
    }
}
```

How can I use this informations to make authorization request to YouTube v3 API? Is it possible?

I've read the doc page and, as far as I understood, I've tried to send a request with this header:

```
{"Authorization" : "Bearer "MY_TOKEN""}
```

But I get this error:

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

Comment: Maybe the solution to your problem is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125330/youtube-analytics-api-403-error

Comment: @MarkoLetic I would like to directly user the firebase auth information